# Vuetify form with validation component shows on page load despite v-if

Tags: css, vue.js, transition, vuetify.js

I have a compnent (custom styled button) that I want to show when the form is successfully validated using vuetify :rules.
However somehow when using transition in order to smoothly show the component, on initial page load it displays that component briefly for a second then it fades out. It does not happen if I dont use transition though (it remains invisible when the page loads).

It works normally after that but I dont want it to briefly appear on initial page load.

Here is the form:

```
 <v-form
     ref="form"
     v-model="valid"
     :lazy-validation="lazy" 
     >
        <v-text-field
                v-model="sepalLength"
                label="Sepal Length"
                required
                :rules="numberRule"
         ></v-text-field>

     <transition name="fade">
          <new-button v-if="valid"></new-button>
     </transition>
</v-form>
```

And the css for the transition

```
<style scoped>
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}

</style>
```

EDIT, here is data model for validation:

```
data: () => ({
        valid: true,

        numberRule: [
          v => !!v || 'Required',
          v => (!isNaN(parseFloat(v))) || 'Must be float']
      }),
```

Comment: could you show your data model

Comment: where did you update initialize the value of valid variable ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 added it

Comment: is the default value of valid is true ? then definitely it will show in first load

Comment: well you have `valid` set intially as `true`, so no surprise there. Set it as `false`